# kill a process in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to kill and restart a process and this command works on interactive mode but not in script mode.

Any suggestion:

```
echo "Killing the running server"
kill $(ps -a | grep 'myserver.jar' | awk '{print $2}') ||  echo 'No active myserver' ; exit 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work:

```
v=$(pgrep -f myserver.jar)
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    kill $v
else 
    echo "no server"
fi
# start server...
```

Answer (score 0):

When a command runs fine in interactive and not in [ batch, crontab, ... take your own ], you should double check :

- you are using same shell (and not eg bash in interactive and bourne shell in batch)
- you have same PATH

If it's not enough look at all environment variables ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider trying `pkill`:

```
pkill myserver.jar
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MichaelWalz How do you know it doesn't provide an answer? If you know what the answer is, please tell me.

Comment: This should be a comment if you are not sure that this is actually the answer.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I don't mean to be argumentative, but I am often not sure my answer is exactly correct, or what the OP was really looking for - especially as questions are often poorly expressed. I still think it constitutes a constructive suggestion that may help the OP and he is welcome to accept it or not. Also, sometimes my answers, and other people's, are incomplete, but they may be a pointer to solving the problem and I think they are legitimate answers too. By your logic, you should also tell "perreal" that his answer should be a comment because he too only says his answer may work.